# Add compiler stage

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, icc

I need to debug a C code with lots of macros, of which a bunch of them are not trivial at all and they include several (lots of) lines. That makes it impossible to debug, since macros are expanded in a single line and you never know where an error comes from. On the other hand, its easy with `sed` to take the preprocessor output and add lines after each semicolon.

I won't discuss about being a good practice to use macros such as these, because I can't do much about that. But I'd like to know whether I could add an stage to the compiler (I use several compilers:icc,gcc,xlc) between preprocessing and compiling, so it I rund that `sed` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now, I will try with what I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor). I also tried the option of the wrapper for compiling single files and, by the moment, it does the trick. In the wrapper, I preprocess (with -E) the file, I then process the preprocessed file with `sed` and some rules, and then I compile it.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to run the pre-processor only (-E):

```
 $ g++ -E in.c -o in.i
```

Then run your sed script and compile it's output with g++ (no -E this time). You could construct a rule for doing all this in your Makefile, I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, I could, but there are lots of Makefiles and rules that would change. I wonder if there is a way to specifically tell the compiler to do something between one compilation stage and the other.

Comment: I don't think gcc has anything like that, maybe other compilers do have it.

Comment: @Genís, a standard trick is to use a wrapper script which will call `g++` twice, adding `-E` and changing `-o` file name for the first run.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own "compiler" as a script to run `g++ -E`, then your `sed`-mangler, then `g++`, and specify that one as the compiler overall. Take care to use temporaries courtesy of `mktemp`, so starting your compiles in parallel (`make -j`) doesn't mess things up.

(Today's GCC doesn't have a separate preprocessing step anymore, so injecting something there can't be done easily anyway.)