# Preprocessing time in gcc (measurement methods)

Tags: gcc, time, c-preprocessor

Is there a method to measure the time taken by the Preprocessor to make its steps? Or is this just straightforward, counting lines of code (more lines of code -> more time taken for preprocessing)?

Comment: Are you asking this in terms of "the fraction of compile time taken by the preprocessor"? May I ask why you need to know?

Comment: `time gcc -E source.c` it's roughly enough to give you an idea.

Comment: @Floris I think i mean just the first 4 steps in translation phase. I want to know how to use structures effictively.

Comment: @user2485710 Thanks, that worked. But the values are somehow volatile - differences up  to 100% for sys. The time function seems to apply to some other processes, which I can't really specify so far.

Comment: "I want to know how to use structures effictively". Not by measuring preprocessing times, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

From [Custom gcc preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor) and using [time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) you can write the following wrapper around `cc1`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "cc1 $*" >&2
time $(${COLLECT_GCC} --print-prog-name=cc1) "$@"
```

The wrapper outputs `cc1` commmand with arguments and the time it taken:

```
$ gcc -no-integrated-cpp -B$PWD 1.c
cc1 -E -quiet 1.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -o /tmp/cckqYvRJ.i

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.005s
cc1 -fpreprocessed /tmp/cckqYvRJ.i -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase 1.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -o /tmp/ccePvbYm.s

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.015s
sys 0m0.006s
```

The time below `cc1 -E ..`  is the time taken by the preprocessor.

If you are referring to measuring time taken by each of the [translation phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) separately, then no, it is not possible. The phases are not done "separately" - all of them, at once, intermixed, are done by one program. The end result is "as-if" the phases would be done one after the other. From the link, emphasis mine:

> The C source file is processed by the compiler **as if** the following phases take place, in this exact order. Actual implementation **may combine these actions or process them differently as long as the behavior is the same**.