# How to define "define" as a macro, is it possible?

Tags: c++, macros, user-defined-functions

I wonder that is it possible to define "define" as a macro?
Like that

```
#define A #define
A MAX_SIZE 100
A MIN_SIZE 0
```

Can I define it? (in c++)

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do?

Comment: You should not obfuscate your code. If you are too lazy to type, use an editor with text-completion.

Comment: You can do it but the pre-processor won't interpret it as a directive, you you'd end up with a literal `#define MAX_SIZE 100` in your code that will lead to a syntax error during the compilation phase.

Comment: I heard you like defines - so I put some defines in your defines so you can define while you define... Seriously, even if that worked, that would be a bad idea. Constants are a better way of doing this in C++.

Comment: Guys, I know how to use #define and why it uses. But, i have limit of character. So I have to complete my code as short as possible.

Comment: If you want short code (golfing?) then write 0 as 0. You're not going to get shorter than that. And `int x=100,u=50;` is also shorter than macro definitions. Iow, macros suck even in golf. (You can shorten typenames with `typedef` but it's rarele useful.)

Answer (score 5):

No. The result of macro expansions will not be treated as new macro directives.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, because the second `#define` won't be parsed as another preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own custom preprocessor to do this, like in this post:

[Custom gcc preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor)