# Access specifier for Has-A relationship

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make a member variable/function has the same access ability of `private` plus accessibility from the class that it is member of?

In code:

```
class A{
Has-A specifier: //imaginary syntax
    int x;
};
class B{
    void do_somthing(){
        a.x=5; //OK
    }
    A a;
};
int main(){
     A.x=5 // Denied- x is not accessible 
}
```

In other words, I want that the `class B` to be `friend` automatically without adding any code line to any class that relate to it with Has-A relationship. Is it possible?

Note: I know that `friendship` will allow it to access all its private members not just `x`. If it could `friendship` on variable/function level, it would be great. If not, a global `friendship` is also nice.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Sent a clearer proposal to the [c++ standards commitee](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee).

Comment: Making `A::x` protected, and inheriting `B` from `A` perhaps?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sure you have reasons to write that as a comment instead of an answer? If the question is a duplicate of a standards committe proposal it must be a pretty good question!

Comment: @JackDeeth Well, I'm not sure if you could achieve something like that using some template meta programming trickery already, but I'm actually too lazy to research about that.

Comment: One way would be to write a custom preprocessor, as described, for example, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor.

Comment: Another way could be to use preprocessor makros like "#ifndef memberpublic #define memberpublic private: " where class A is defined, and override this definition with #define memberpublic public: where ever the headerfile of class A is to be included and access to A.x shall be permitted.  Still tricky and error prone, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the following setup in XCode with apple compiler and GNU++ language dialect; the setup has to be used - if to be used at all - with care. See remarks at the end of the answer.

Suppose a header file defining class A as follows:

```cpp
// testprivateA.h:
#ifndef memberpublic
#define memberpublic private:
#endif

class A {

memberpublic

    int x;
};

#undef memberpublic
```

... and a separate headerfile defining class B:

```cpp
// testprivateB.h:
#include "testprivateA.h"

class B {

public:
    void test();

    A a;
};
```

At the place where member function `B::test()` is implemented, define `memberpublic` as `public:`:

```cpp
// testprivateB.cpp:
#define memberpublic public:
#include "testprivateB.h"

void B::test()
{
    a.x = 5;  // OK
}
```

Whereas at any other place, where class `A` is used, let `memberpublic` remain undefined; accessing member variable `A.x` then yields a compiler error:

```cpp
// anyOtherFile.cpp:
#include "testprivateB.h"
void testfail()
{
    A a;
    a.x = 5; // Error: 'x' is a private member of 'A'
}
```

One now may ask if this behaviour is according to c++ standard or not. And the answer to this question is - actually not (though it took me a while to find out why).

Though there may be more than one definition of a class in a program, above setting contradicts the [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), because different access specifiers lead to different sequences of tokens:

> There can be more than one definition in a program, as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit, of each of the following: class type, enumeration type, inline function with external linkage inline variable with external linkage (since C++17), class template, non-static function template, static data member of a class template, member function of a class template, partial template specialization, as long as all of the following is true:
>   **- each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)**

Still it could work, but the main issue is the connection of memory layout and access specifiers as defined in [access specifiers - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> Any number of access specifiers may appear within a class, in any order. Member **access specifiers may affect class layout**: the addresses of non-static data members are only guaranteed to increase in order of declaration for the members with the same access. For StandardLayoutType, all non-static data members must have the same access. ...

Still it can work, if all non-static data members in the respective class have the same access specifier. If it is a good solution, one may decide...

Comment: Hm... I'll be interested in hearing from someone who knows the C++ Standard better than I do as to whether or not this behavior is standardized.

Comment: @Silvio: I spent some more time in investigating standard conformity. Results say that my proposed solution is not standard conform, and it 'could' work only for specific cases. Nevertheless, I kept the solution and discussed this topic at the end of the answer.